# How to generate Product link?

Tags: android, android-intent, share, share-intent

I want share url of product, product name to some user using either what's app or facebook etc.when user clicks on that product same product page in app should be opened if app is installed. if app is not installed it should navigate to play store.Now how to generate that sharable link so that same page in app should be opened when user clicks

Here is my code

```
// share on social websites
    public void shareItem(String url) {
        Log.e("image",productimage);
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url).into(new Target() {
            @Override public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("*/*");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getLocalBitmapUri(bitmap));
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, name.getText().toString()+ "\n" +productimage);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share Image"));
            }
            @Override public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) { }
            @Override public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) { }
        });
    }
    public Uri getLocalBitmapUri(Bitmap bmp) {
        Uri bmpUri = null;
        try {
            File file =  new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            out.close();
            //bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            bmpUri=FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplication(),BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider",file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bmpUri;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add an intent filter in  manifest file. An intent filter should contain the following elements and attribute values;

Define ACTION_VIEW intent action so that the intent filter can be reached from Google Search.

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
```

We should include the BROWSABLE category in order to be accessible from a web browser. We should also have DEFAULT category for responding to implicit intents

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
```

Lastly, We should define one or more  tags. Each of these tags represents a URI format that resolves to the activity. The following example represents a simple data tag for test.com Android app.

```
 <data
        android:host="test.com"
        android:scheme="https" />
```

**How to read data from incoming intents**

When you define your intent filter that can handle specific URLs, the system can start your activity via that intent filter.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri data = intent.getData();
```

if you pass the query parameter as test.com?productID=123 you can retrieve it from

```
data.getQueryParameter("productID");
```

Comment: where to pass product id in link so that exact product should open

Comment: example http://www.example.com/test?data=12345
from this 

Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri data = intent.getData();

you can get the parameter data

Comment: i think you are trying to get  image url from deeplink and pass it to  shareItem(String url) this method right

Comment: image url is not necessary sir. www.domain.com/product id like that

Comment: check once i have edited the  answer if you pass the query parameter as test.com?productID=123 you can retrieve it from

data.getQueryParameter("productId");

Comment: thanks for ur patience. how to change this   i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, name.getText().toString()+ "\n" +productimage);

Comment: productimage should contain url now

Comment: how to modify my code to get url "www.abc.com/productid =12345"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190082/discussion-between-lasya-valiveti-and-bharat-kumar-emani).